# How to Write a Custom Snitch for Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm currently attempting to write a new snitch that makes minor tweaks and improvements to SimpleSnitch that comes with the "out of the box" Apache Cassandra.

My current objective is, instead of the pre-made Dynamic Snitch that comes as a wrapper of subsnitches provided by Cassandra, to create my own snitch that is able to inform Cassandra about which nodes to send requests to. Whereas most snitches simply inform Cassandra about the topology of the network, I want to inform Cassandra about which node to send to, and where that node resides.

My main trouble is finding how to get my snitch to interact with Cassandra in a way that exceeds the scope of requesting for topological data. For example, my `public String getDatacenter(InetAddress endpoint)` function is actively being called, however this is the only function in my program that is called by Cassandra. I would love to be able to write some function, `public String getBestNode()`, that returns the IP of the node to Cassandra when it requests for it. However, I can't seem to find any information online that provides me with functions to override/write myself that Cassandra calls for.

If anyone has a good Snitch writing resource they could link me, that would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise, I would be thankful for any advice anyone has for me.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to achieve... If you want that clients sent requests to "best" node, then you need to look to driver side, not into Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex and absolutely.   
So I currently have a network that is constantly pinging each-other and finding the best latency. The IP of the best latency node is then written to a file, and this is where I would like my snitch to kick into action. So essentially what I want to achieve here is the ability to override the dynamic snitch (which I've gone ahead and disabled in my cassandra.yaml) and basically tell Cassandra to forward all future requests to the best latency node I found earlier. With this description, would you still suggest looking into the driver side?

Comment: I've gotten Cassandra to recognize and use my custom snitches, but it would seem that I only have a topological influence on Cassandra with my custom snitch. It seems the only way I can actually affect this process is to directly edit DynamicEndpointSnitch.java and re-enable dynamic snitch in the cassandra.yaml, however I'm not sure how Cassandra compiles its source code because even if I edit the file and restart the Cassandra service, my changes are not seen in the system log.

Comment: I suggest that you do it on the driver side, not on Cassandra side... But be very careful with that, as the latency is not the only parameter that you need to take into consideration.

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly take that second part into consideration as well. If I could inquire from you one last time, is there a particular directory/module that you would suggest I inspect/edit?

Comment: I would start with this: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/load_balancing/ (for older driver) or https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/load_balancing/ for new driver